# Can we use Dirichlet process to simultaneously estimate the number of mixtures and component distribution of a Bernoulli mixture?

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, finite-mixture-model, dirichlet-process, discrete-distributions

Suppose I have a random sample on a Bernoulli random variable $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ generated from model $p=\sum_{k=1}^K\pi_kp_k$,where $p\equiv Pr(X=1)$ and $p_k\equiv Pr(X=1|k)$, and $\pi_k$ are the mixing weight satisfying $\sum_k\pi_k=1$.

Can we use the Dirichlet process to **simultaneously estimate the number of mixtures** $K$ and **component distribution** $\{p_k\}_{k=1}^K$ of a Bernoulli mixture? If yes, how to proceed?

If it doesn't work, why? And does the following two cases work:

Case1. I have a random sample on $T\geq 2$ Bernoulli random variables $\{(X_{1i},...,X_{Ti})\}_{i=1}^N$, where $X_{1i},...,X_{Ti}\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}p=\sum_{k=1}^K\pi_kp_k$.

Case2. I have a random sample $\{Y_{i}\}_{i=1}^N$ on a discrete ranodm variable $Y$ with more than 2 points in its support , where $Y_{i}\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}F=\sum_{k=1}^K\pi_kF_k$, where $F$ is the unconditional cdf for $Y$, and $F_k$ is the cdf on component $k$.

Some sample codes, or good reference papers are welcome.

Comment: Check https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07194

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you very much! This looks relevant.